# How to pattern fill an image using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I want to pattern fill an image with couple of images. The border with one image and the inside with another image. Can anyone please help

```
[Input image][1]
[Skin 1][2]
[Skin 2][3]

  [1]: https://pasteboard.co/KbfG8qU.png
  [2]: https://pasteboard.co/KbfGE4M.jpg
  [3]: https://pasteboard.co/KbfGUy56.png
```

Comment: Please provide an example output. What is the border?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/KbiMuNt.png, this image has the black borders filled with skin 1. I want the inside to be filled with skin 2

Comment: commands used :

convert input.png -alpha extract mask.png

convert input.png -alpha off -evaluate add 50% -sigmoidal-contrast 20,50% 2_mod.png

convert 2_mod.png ( -clone 0 -resize 400% -tile skin.jpg -draw "color 0,0 reset" -resize 25% ) -compose hardlight -composite  mask.png -alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite out.png

Comment: That does not show me what the result should look like. Please post an example.

Comment: This is the best i could make manually, https://pasteboard.co/KbjoaSp.png
The white spaces that you see should also contain the pattern. I hope i am clear with the output i am expecting. Also I am using IM 6.9 in windows

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that in Imagemagick. I first tile the two skin images to the size of the frame. Then I composite the skin1 border over the skin2 background. Then I create a mask that flood fills the outside with transparency and the rest to white and then turn off transparency to leave black outside and the rest white. Then I put that mask into the alpha channel of the skinned image.

Frame image:

[image]

Skin1:

[image]

Skin2:

[image]

Imagemagick 6 Unix Syntax:

```
convert frame.png -write mpr:img +delete \
\( mpr:img -alpha off -tile skin2.png -draw "color 0,0 reset" \) \
\( mpr:img -alpha off -tile skin1.jpeg -draw "color 0,0 reset" \) \
\( mpr:img -alpha extract -write mpr:alpha \) \
-compose over -composite \
\( mpr:alpha -fill "none" -draw "matte 0,0 floodfill" -fill white +opaque none \) \
-alpha off -compose over -compose copy_opacity -composite \
result.png
```

[Result](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/frame_skin1_skin2.png)

(Image is too large to upload)

For Windows syntax, remove \ from parentheses and change end of line \ to ^.

For Imagemagick 7, change convert to magick and matte to alpha.

ADDITION:

If you are on IM 7 and want to stretch the texture to the size of the frame as in the comment, then you can do that in one command. In IM 6, you would need to find the size of the frame in a prior command.

Background texture:

[image]

Skin1:

[image]

Frame:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sir you are a champion. Also if I want to use color gradient instead of skin2 what changes would it need ?

Comment: Show me the kind of color gradient you want.

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/KbkeW4N.jpg something like this like a shadow effect to make it look like 3d

Comment: I do not understand how that would be compatible with the background texture fill region. I do not know how to scale it to fit. It is also a different shape.  I consider a gradient a gradual color change from one color to another. If you can create the texture for the fill area of the inside, then just replace that for the first parentheses in my command.

Comment: I am having one issue related to the previous solution. When i use a skin: https://pasteboard.co/KbpqJi6.jpg, it gives result as: https://pasteboard.co/KbpqBaF.png. There is a line that comes, can we not have the full image filled, if the skin image is small it can strech to fill rather than create duplicates.

Comment: The edges of your input have a white region. Just chop that off first. The texture can be resized, but you would need to know the size you want to stretch it ahead of time.

Comment: I have modified my answer to show an example of stretching the texture to fill the frame, but showing it only inside the black lines as requested.